# How to make clone of JotForm?

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs, scriptaculous

I have recently looked at [jotForm](http://www.jotform.com/) which ia very Interactive form Builder. They have used Prototype JS library. What can be a good base for making a similar form Builder. Jquery, Prototype , Scriptaculus or Any other JS framework/Library

Comment: This might be facetious; Why don't you just use jotForm?

Comment: I am in need of some of my own custom elements to be included in the control box so i have to make a form builder for that.....

Answer (score 0):

JotForm is actually available, they have JotForm Licensing Solution. Please visit this page for more informations: http://www.interlogy.com/products/jotform/

It comes with Free Installation =)